# Performing RK4 between two cluster

Tags: c++, c++17, runge-kutta

I have a simulated data of charged particles in a magnetic field. I have selected clusters, each cluster contains a set of points(x,z) and I want to perform RK4 between the first and second clusters and fill the positions in a histogram.

I have selected the clusters with the initial conditions(positions and velocity). but the thing is I have performed the rk4 but it is not behaving like I want and I am not able to perform the rk4 between the two clusters. Here is my code:

```
Double_t dxdt(double t,double vx, double vy, Double_t vz){

Double_t Energy = GetEnergy(vx, vy, vz);
Double_t st = StoppingPower(Energy);
Double_t Ex,Ey,Ez,f1; //Electric field in V/m.
Double_t Bx,By,Bz; // magnetic field in Tesla
Double_t rr,az,po;
Double_t q = 1.6022*TMath::Power(10,-19); //charge of the particle(proton) in (C)
Double_t m = 1.6726*TMath::Power(10,-27); // mass of the particle in kg
Double_t B= -3.0; // Applied magnetic field (T).
Double_t E=TMath::Cos((q*B)/m) * 500; // Applied Electric field(V/m).
Bx = 0;
By = 0; // magnetic field in x and y direction in Tesla.
Bz = B; // magnetic field in the z direction in Tesla.
Ex = 0;
Ey = 0; // Electric field in the x and direction in V/m.
Ez = -E; // Electric field in the z direction.


rr = TMath::Sqrt(TMath::Power(vx,2)+TMath::Power(vy,2)+TMath::Power(vz,2));
az = TMath::ATan2(vy,vx);
po = TMath::ACos(vz/rr);

f1 = q/m * (Ex + vy*Bz-vz*By) - st*TMath::Sin(po)*TMath::Cos(az); //-s*TMath::Sin(po)*TMath::Cos(az) ; //dxdt with energyloss compensation.

double bro = Bz * rr / TMath::Sin(po)/ 1000.0;
//cout<<Energy<<endl;
//cout<<bro<<endl;
//std::cout<<Ex <<" "<< vy<<" "<<vz << " " <<By<< " "<< f1<<std::endl;
return f1;

}

double dydt(double t,double vx, double vy, Double_t vz){
Double_t Energy = GetEnergy(vx, vy, vz);
Double_t st = StoppingPower(Energy);
Double_t Ex,Ey,Ez,f2; //Electric field in V/m.
Double_t Bx,By,Bz; // magnetic field in Tesla
Double_t q = 1.6022*TMath::Power(10,-19); //charge of the particle in C
Double_t B= -3.0; // Applied magnetic field.
Double_t rr,az,po;
Double_t m = 1.6726*TMath::Power(10,-27); // mass of the particle in kg
Double_t E = TMath::Cos((q*B)/m) * 500 ;
Bx = 0; // magnetic field in x and y direction in Tesla.
By = 0;
Bz = B; // magnetic field in the z direction in Tesla.
Ex = 0; // Electric field in the x and direction in V/m.
Ey = 0;
Ez = -E; // Electric field in the z direction.

rr = TMath::Sqrt(TMath::Power(vx,2)+TMath::Power(vy,2)+TMath::Power(vz,2));
az = TMath::ATan(vy/vx);
po = TMath::ACos(vz/rr);


f2 = q/m * (Ey + vz*Bx - vx*Bz) - st*TMath::Sin(po)*TMath::Sin(az);

double bro = Bz * rr / TMath::Sin(po)/ 1000.0;
//cout<<bro<<endl;
//cout<<Energy<<endl;
//std::cout<<f2<<std::endl;
return f2;
}

double dzdt(double t,double vx, double vy,Double_t vz){
Double_t Energy = GetEnergy(vx, vy, vz);
Double_t st = StoppingPower(Energy);
Double_t Ex,Ey,Ez,f3; //Electric field in V/m.
Double_t Bx,By,Bz; // magnetic field in Tesla
Double_t q = 1.6022*pow(10,-19); //charge of the particle in eV
Double_t B= -3.0; // Applied magnetic field.
Double_t rr,az,po;
Double_t m = 1.6726*TMath::Power(10,-27); // mass of the particle in kg
Double_t E = TMath::Cos((q*B)/m) * 500 ;
Bx = 0; // magnetic field in x and y direction in Tesla.
By = 0;
Bz = B; // magnetic field in the z direction in Tesla.
Ex = 0; // Electric field in the x and direction in V/m.
Ey = 0;
Ez = -E; // Electric field in the z direction.

rr = TMath::Sqrt(TMath::Power(vx,2)+TMath::Power(vy,2)+TMath::Power(vz,2));
az = TMath::ATan(vy/vx);
//std::cout<<az<<endl;
po = TMath::ACos(vz/rr);


f3 = q/m * (Ez + vx*By - vy*Bx)- st*TMath::Cos(po);
double bro = Bz * rr / TMath::Sin(po)/ 1000.0;
//cout<<bro<<endl;
//cout<<Energy<<endl<<endl;
//std::cout <<r<< " " << TMath::Power(vy,2) + TMath::Power(vx,2) + TMath::Power(vz,2)<< " " << TMath::Power(vz,2) << std::endl;
return f3;
}

// Functions for positions.

Double_t fx(Double_t t, Double_t vx){


Double_t f1x = vx;
return f1x;


}

Double_t fy(Double_t t,Double_t vy){


Double_t f2y = vy;
return f2y;


}

Double_t fz(Double_t t,Double_t vz){

Double_t f3z = vz;
return f3z;

}
 firstCluster = hitClusterArray->at(0);
    secondCluster = hitClusterArray->at(1);
    firstPosition = firstCluster.GetPosition();
    secondPosition = secondCluster.GetPosition();
 
    Double_t iniPx, iniPy, iniPz;
    Double_t iniVx1, iniVy1, iniVz1;

    Double_t secPosX,secPosY,secPosZ;
    Double_t iniPosX,iniPosY,iniPosZ;

    secPosX = secondPosition.X();
    secPosY = secondPosition.Y();
    secPosZ = secondPosition.Z();
    iniPosX = firstPosition.X();
    iniPosY = firstPosition.Y();
    iniPosZ = firstPosition.Z();

    phi = TMath::ATan2(secPosY- iniPosY, secPosX - iniPosX);
    Double_t phiDeg;
    if (phi < 0){
    phiDeg = 360+ phi*TMath::RadToDeg();
    }  else {
    phiDeg = phi*TMath::RadToDeg();
    }

    iniPx = p * TMath::Cos(phiDeg*TMath::DegToRad()) * TMath::Sin(theta);        // in MeV/c
    iniPy = p * TMath::Sin(phiDeg*TMath::DegToRad()) * TMath::Sin(theta);              // in MeV/c
    iniPz = p * TMath::Cos(theta);                                              // in MeV/c


    iniVx1 = (iniPx * 5.344286e-22)/m; //meter per second [m/s]
    iniVy1 = (iniPy * 5.344286e-22)/m;
    iniVz1 = (iniPz * 5.344286e-22)/m;
    int clusterCount = 0;
    for (auto iCluster = 0; iCluster < hitClusterArray->size(); ++iCluster) {
    auto cluster = hitClusterArray->at(iCluster);
    auto pos = cluster.GetPosition();

    Double_t clusterPosX = pos.X();
    Double_t clusterPosY = pos.Y();
    Double_t clusterPosZ = pos.Z();

    //std::cout<<iniPosX << " " << iniPosY << " "<< iniPosZ <<endl << endl;
    for (pp =  0; pp< 100; pp++){

    l1x[pp] = fx(t1,iniPx1);
    l1y[pp] = fy(t1,iniPy1);
    l1z[pp] = fz(t1,iniPz1);

    l1vx[pp] = dxdt(t1,iniPx1,iniPy1,iniPz1);
    l1vy[pp] = dydt(t1,iniPx1,iniPy1,iniPz1);
    l1vz[pp] = dzdt(t1,iniPx1,iniPy1,iniPz1);

    l2x[pp] = fx(t1+h*0.5,iniPx1+0.5*h*l1x[pp]);
    l2y[pp] = fy(t1+h*0.5,iniPy1+0.5*h*l1y[pp]);
    l2z[pp] = fz(t1+h*0.5,iniPz1+0.5*h*l1z[pp]);

    l2vx[pp] =dxdt(t1+h*0.5,iniPx1+l1vx[pp]*0.5*h,iniPy1+l1vy[pp]*h*0.5,iniPz1+l1vz[pp]*h*0.5);
    l2vy[pp] =dydt(t1+h*0.5,iniPx1+l1vx[pp]*h*0.5,iniPy1+l1vy[pp]*h*0.5,iniPz1+l1vz[pp]*h*0.5);
    l2vz[pp] =dzdt(t1+h*0.5,iniPx1+l1vx[pp]*h*0.5,iniPy1+l1vy[pp]*h*0.5,iniPz1+l1vz[pp]*h*0.5);

    l3x[pp] = fx(t1+h*0.5,iniPx1+0.5*h*l2x[pp]);
       l3y[pp] = fy(t1+h*0.5,iniPy1+0.5*h*l2y[pp]);
       l3z[pp] = fz(t1+h*0.5,iniPz1+0.5*h*l2z[pp]);
       l3vx[pp] =dxdt(t1+h*0.5,iniPx1+l2vx[pp]*0.5*h,iniPy1+l2vy[pp]*h*0.5,iniPz1+l2vz[pp]*h*0.5);
       l3vy[pp] =dydt(t1+h*0.5,iniPx1+l2vx[pp]*h*0.5,iniPy1+l2vy[pp]*h*0.5,iniPz1+l2vz[pp]*h*0.5);
       l3vz[pp] =dzdt(t1+h*0.5,iniPx1+l2vx[pp]*h*0.5,iniPy1+l2vy[pp]*h*0.5,iniPz1+l2vz[pp]*h*0.5);

       l4x[pp] = fx(t1+h,iniPx1+l3x[pp]*h);
       l4y[pp] = fy(t1+h,iniPy1+l3y[pp]*h);
       l4z[pp] = fz(t1+h,iniPz1+l3z[pp]*h);

       l4vx[pp] = dxdt(t1+h,iniPx1+l3vx[pp]*h,iniPy1+l3vy[pp]*h,iniPz1+l3vz[pp]*h);
       l4vy[pp] = dydt(t1+h,iniPx1+l3vx[pp]*h,iniPy1+l3vy[pp]*h,iniPz1+l3vz[pp]*h);
       l4vz[pp] = dzdt(t1+h,iniPx1+l3vx[pp]*h,iniPy1+l3vy[pp]*h,iniPz1+l3vz[pp]*h);


      iniPx1 = iniPx1 + h/6 *( l1vx[pp] + 2*l2vx[pp] + 2*l3vx[pp] + l4vx[pp]);
      iniPy1  = iniPy1 + h/6 *(l1vy[pp] + 2*l2vy[pp] + 2*l3vy[pp] + l4vy[pp]);
      iniPz1  = iniPz1 + h/6 *(l1vz[pp] + 2*l2vz[pp] + 2*l3vz[pp] + l4vz[pp]);

      iniPosX = iniPosX + h/6 *( l1x[pp]  + 2*l2x[pp] + 2*l3x[pp] + l4x[pp]);
      iniPosY  = iniPosY + h/6 *( l1y[pp] + 2*l2y[pp] + 2*l3y[pp] + l4y[pp]);
      iniPosZ  = iniPosZ + h/6 *( l1z[pp] + 2*l2z[pp] + 2*l3z[pp] + l4z[pp]);
                                   
     
         kx_vs_ky->Fill(iniPosX, iniPosY);

      }

       //Update the initial conditions for the next cluster
         iniPosX = clusterPosX;
         iniPosY = clusterPosY;
         iniPosZ = clusterPosZ;
                                
          ++clusterCount;
       if (clusterCount > 2) {
           break; // stop iterating over clusters after the second one
           }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are doing more carefully. What does “between clusters” mean? What does “it is not behaving like I want” mean? We can’t see what routines fx() and dxdt() do. There doesn’t appear to be anything wrong with your Runge-Kutta routine … but the function arguments suggest that there is no interaction between different particles.

Comment: basically between clusters means between two points. first cluster and second cluster. the functions contains the equations of motions of charged particles in magnetic field. I want to take the two points and perform the rk4 between the two points. So I am expecting that the particles(first cluster) propagates in the rk4 to the second cluster.

Comment: But your calls like ```l3vx[pp] =dxdt(....pp...)``` only involve particle pp and not the other particles. Physically, your problem doesn't seem to make sense: every charged particle interacts with every other one, not just those in a particular cluster. You would really need to show edit your post to show complete code and also the equations that you are trying to represent.

Comment: I have edited the code to include the equations I am trying to solve. Equation of motions for charge particle in electric and magnetic field

Comment: thank-you for including your code. You are apparently moving the particles (via the Lorentz force) in externally-imposed electric and magnetic fields (0,0,-E) and (0,0,B). But your question suggests that you want the electromagnetic force between the individual particles (for which dxdt etc need to know position and velocity of ALL particles). Your code is also broken down too much into coordinates: you shouldn't need separate dxdt, dydt, dzdt functions, for example.

Comment: Exactly what I need but I am new to c++ and that was how I thought it should be

Comment: I should pass all the particles' position and velocity data as arrays to a single derivative routine (which presumably needs to update and return one or more arrays containing the acceleration of each particle). Calculate the Lorentz forces between each pair of particles and, for each particle, sum the forces on that and divide by the mass to get the acceleration. Don't lose the physics within the challenge of the coding.